# ORA-06550: line 3, column 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "1" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, google-maps

I get this error message:

> ORA-06550: line 3, column 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "1"

when expecting one of the following:

> begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior

For this code in oracle apex web application:

```
declare
  1_address  varchar2(4000);
  1_url      varchar2(32000);
  1_response varchar2(3200);
begin
  1_address := :P3_STREET || ',' || :P3_CITY;
  if :P3_STATE is not null then
    1_address := 1_address || ',' || :P3_STATE;
  end if;
  if :P3_COUNTRY is not null then
    1_address := 1_address || ',' || :P3_COUNTRY;
  end if;
  1_address := replace(1_address, ' ', '+');

  1_url        := 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=' || 1_address || '&' ||
                  'output=c sv' || '&' || 'key=' || :API_KEY;
  1_response   := utl_http.request(1_url, APEX_APPLICATION.G_PROXY_SERVER);
  :P3_RESPONSE := 1_response;
  :P3_LOCATION := substr(1_response, instr(1_response, ',', 1, 2) + 1);
end;
```

I would like to integrate google maps to my application.

I followed [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/integrating-apex-with-google-maps-169532.pdf) instruction, but it doesn't work.

Anybody have idea for solution?

Comment: Please edit your code so it is readable.  Hint:  use the `{}` button for code or put four spaces at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle naming conventions require (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)):

5. Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

The same also applies to PL/SQL variable names (see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0420__PL-SQL-Data-Types/VariableNamingRules.htm)):

> Variable names can be composed of letters, dollar signs, underscores,
>   and number signs.
>
> No other characters can be used.
>
> **A variable name must start with a letter, after which any combination
>   of the allowed characters can be used.**
>
> The maximum length for a variable name is 30 characters.
>
> Variable names, like those of keywords and other identifiers, are not
>   case sensitive.

So, change the name of your variables to something that is acceptable to Oracle.  In other words, don't start them with `1`.

Comment: As a complement, it is a common practice to start _local variables_ by the letter `l`.

Here you have simply mistaken them for `1` (the digit _one_) while copying the code.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux . . . That is an excellent point.  I hadn't thought of that and it makes a lot of sense.